# Vue 3 and Vuetify 3: V-Menu moving when a v-chip is showed up

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using Vue 3 and Vutify 3 and I have v-menus with datatables inside. When I select items I show a v-chips in the V-btn with the amount of selected items.

But when the v-chip appear, the V-menu moving (because the V-btn expands).

Tried to use an anchor and put an id (or class) on the icon element, but I got an error saying the anchor didn't find any Id/class element.

```
<template>
  <v-btn variant="plain" color="black">
    <div class="d-flex align-center">
      {{ title }}

      <v-chip
        v-if="selectedModel.length"
        label
        size="small"
        color="blue"
        class="mx-1"
      >
        {{ selectedModel.length }}
      </v-chip>
    </div>
    <v-icon right> mdi-chevron-down </v-icon>

    <v-menu
      location="bottom center"
      activator="parent"
      :close-on-content-click="false"
    >
      <v-card width="350">
        <v-divider />
        <v-divider />
      ...DATATABLE COMPONENT
      </v-card>
    </v-menu>
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As already cited in the [documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#location)-

> The menu can be offset relative to the activator by using the location
> prop.

**This simply implies that it is significantly obvious for a menu to alter its location if its activator element expands/shrinks.**

I tested the `location-strategy prop` as well which didn't work by the way and checked the documentation too but did not find any right way to do this.

However, I came up with two methods to fix the menu position when the activator expands/shrinks. I am just, not sure if these are the right approaches to follow.

Nonetheless, here are the two methods-

**1. Render the count element already-**
Show the count element always but with a condition that when the count is 0, transparent the count's background otherwise gives a color.
In this way, the count element will always be present in the button but invisible until its value increases from 0, so no issue with the button's expanding/shrinking.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"
      rel="stylesheet"
      />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
      <v-app>
        <v-btn @click="resetCount" color="error">Reset count</v-btn>
        <div class="d-flex justify-center mt-5">
          <v-menu position="bottom center" :close-on-content-click="false">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
              <v-btn variant="plain" color="black" v-bind="props" :rounded="0">
                <div class="d-flex align-center">
                  Types
                  <v-chip
                    label
                    size="small"
                    :color="count_a ? 'red' : 'white'"
                    :class="['ms-2']"
                  >
                    {{ count_a }}
                  </v-chip>
                </div>
                <v-icon class="ms-2"> mdi-chevron-down </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                @click="count_a = count_a + 1"
              >
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
          <v-menu position="bottom center" :close-on-content-click="false">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
              <v-btn variant="plain" color="black" v-bind="props" :rounded="0">
                <div class="d-flex align-center">
                  Domains
                  <v-chip
                    label
                    size="small"
                    :color="count_b ? 'red' : 'white'"
                    :class="['ms-2']"
                  >
                    {{ count_b }}
                  </v-chip>
                </div>
                <v-icon class="ms-2"> mdi-chevron-down </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                @click="count_b = count_b + 1"
              >
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
          <v-menu position="bottom center" :close-on-content-click="false">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
              <v-btn variant="plain" color="black" v-bind="props" :rounded="0">
                <div class="d-flex align-center">
                  Languages
                  <v-chip
                    label
                    size="small"
                    :color="count_c ? 'red' : 'white'"
                    :class="['ms-2']"
                  >
                    {{ count_c }}
                  </v-chip>
                </div>
                <v-icon class="ms-2"> mdi-chevron-down </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                @click="count_c = count_c + 1"
              >
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
          <v-menu position="bottom center" :close-on-content-click="false">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
              <v-btn variant="plain" color="black" v-bind="props" :rounded="0">
                <div class="d-flex align-center">
                  Versions
                  <v-chip
                    label
                    size="small"
                    :color="count_d ? 'red' : 'white'"
                    :class="['ms-2']"
                  >
                    {{ count_d }}
                  </v-chip>
                </div>
                <v-icon class="ms-2"> mdi-chevron-down </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                @click="count_d = count_d + 1"
              >
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
        </div>
      </v-app>
    </script>
    <script>
      const { createApp } = Vue;
      const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;
      
      const vuetify = createVuetify();
      
      const app = createApp({
        template: "#app-template",
        data: () => ({
            count_a: 0,
            count_b: 0,
            count_c: 0,
            count_d: 0,
            items: [
                { title: "Click Me" },
                { title: "Click Me" },
                { title: "Click Me" },
                { title: "Click Me 2" },
            ],
        }),
           methods: {
            resetCount() {
             this.count_a = this.count_b = this.count_c = this.count_d = 0
            }
           }
      })
        .use(vuetify)
        .mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**2. Give some minimum width to the activator button-**
If the button would have some minimum width then the count element will first try to adjust itself into the available space without moving the menu element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"
      rel="stylesheet"
      />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
      <v-app>
        <v-btn @click="resetCount" color="error">Reset count</v-btn>
        <div class="d-flex align-center mt-5">
          <v-menu position="bottom center" :close-on-content-click="false" >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
              <v-btn variant="plain" color="black" v-bind="props" :rounded="0" :min-width="200">
                <div class="d-flex align-center">
                  Types
                  <v-chip
                    v-if="count_a"
                    label
                    size="small"
                    color="red"
                    :class="['ms-2']"
                  >
                    {{ count_a }}
                  </v-chip>
                </div>
                <v-icon class="ms-2"> mdi-chevron-down </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                @click="count_a = count_a + 1"
              >
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
          <v-menu position="bottom center" :close-on-content-click="false">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
              <v-btn variant="plain" color="black" v-bind="props" :rounded="0" :min-width="200">
                <div class="d-flex align-center">
                  Domains
                  <v-chip
                    v-if="count_b"
                    label
                    size="small"
                    color="red"
                    :class="['ms-2']"
                  >
                    {{ count_b }}
                  </v-chip>
                </div>
                <v-icon class="ms-2"> mdi-chevron-down </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                @click="count_b = count_b + 1"
              >
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
          <v-menu position="bottom center" :close-on-content-click="false">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
              <v-btn variant="plain" color="black" v-bind="props" :rounded="0" :min-width="200">
                <div class="d-flex align-center">
                  Languages
                  <v-chip
                    v-if="count_c"
                    label
                    size="small"
                    color="red"
                    :class="['ms-2']"
                  >
                    {{ count_c }}
                  </v-chip>
                </div>
                <v-icon class="ms-2"> mdi-chevron-down </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                @click="count_c = count_c + 1"
              >
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
          <v-menu position="bottom center" :close-on-content-click="false">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
              <v-btn variant="plain" color="black" v-bind="props" :rounded="0" :min-width="200">
                <div class="d-flex align-center">
                  Versions
                  <v-chip
                    v-if="count_d"
                    label
                    size="small"
                    color="red"
                    :class="['ms-2']"
                  >
                    {{ count_d }}
                  </v-chip>
                </div>
                <v-icon class="ms-2"> mdi-chevron-down </v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                @click="count_d = count_d + 1"
              >
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
        </div>
      </v-app>
    </script>
    <script>
      const { createApp } = Vue;
      const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;
      
      const vuetify = createVuetify();
      
      const app = createApp({
        template: "#app-template",
        data: () => ({
            count_a: 0,
            count_b: 0,
            count_c: 0,
            count_d: 0,
            items: [
                { title: "Click Me" },
                { title: "Click Me" },
                { title: "Click Me" },
                { title: "Click Me 2" },
            ],
        }),
           methods: {
            resetCount() {
             this.count_a = this.count_b = this.count_c = this.count_d = 0
            }
           }
      })
        .use(vuetify)
        .mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note-** Please test the snippets on the full page because the menu will overlap with the activator in the small window.

Also, please let me know if you come up with a better/right way.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! The solutions proposed are good but I really wanna find something else because both solutions modify the original aspects (before chips are here). First one put an useless space when the chip isn't here. The second put more space between each buttons. Tested also the "location-strategy" prop, and I guess it's not what I want as it detachs the menu from it's parent

Comment: Okay, I'll look more.